# PHP universal CRUD object

Tags: php, database, crud, modularity

I am restructuring all of my system's core objects ( User, Order, Product ect )

They all extend the same CoreObject abstract class.

I'm thinking on a basic level, they will all need CRUD functionality. I'm not sure if i'm overthinking this too much or not, but i'm thinking that I would like to have all CRUD functionality contained in the CoreObject superclass.

So, if I wanted to create a new object, call it Post, I would have CRUD functionality in just a few lines.

My thought was maybe keep along a sort of schema.json file for each object that would map each of the object's properties to the database, table, field, and contain the parameters needed in the query to get to it.

For example, User might have something like:
"email":{
     "database":"mydb",
     "table":"users",
     "field":"userEmail",
     "params":{"id":"$id"}
}

This would say, to get the User email field, select the field userEmail from users table the mydb database where id = the id supplied

So for a new object, i'd just need to add this schema file and it would instantly have basic CRUD functionality.

Is this thought out of line? Has it been done before, if so, what is it called so I may research it?

Comment: Almost every PHP framework has one of these.

Comment: This is the ActiveRecord design pattern, for which Laravel's Eloquent is an excellent example IMO.